# Active Anchor Navigation

Tags: jquery, css, smooth-scrolling

My single page website currently smooth scrolls to anchors with arrow keys. The problem is when you scroll to each section the link thats hovered doesn't follow each section as your over it. It only follows your arrow key commands. How can I change this? This is the current website (http://www.jonasandnicole.com)

CSS

```
nav.desktop a {
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:20px;
    color:#CCC;
    -moz-transition: background 0.7s ease;
    -ms-transition: background 0.7s ease;
    -o-transition: background 0.7s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.7s ease;
}
nav.desktop a:hover {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color:#fff;
}
.selected {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

jQuery

```
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".desktop a").click(function() {
        $(".desktop a").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected"); 
    });
});
$(function() {
    var lengthDiv = $('.desktop').find('li').length;
    var current = 0;
    $('a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);
        current = $anchor.parent().index();

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href#')).offset().top
        }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
        /*
        if you don't want to use the easing effects:
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1000);
        */
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $(document).keydown(function(e){if($(':focus').length <= 0)e.preventDefault()})
    $(document).keyup(function(e){
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if(key == 38 && current > 0){
            $('.desktop').children('li').eq(current - 1).children('a').trigger('click')
        }else if(key == 40 && current < lengthDiv){
            $('.desktop').children('li').eq(current + 1).children('a').trigger('click')
        }
    })
});

</script>
```

Comment: You could check the offset from the top, and once it passes certain points, apply the active effect to the link.

Comment: Possible duplicat [Change Active Menu Item on Page Scroll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979827/change-active-menu-item-on-page-scroll).

Comment: even with a responsive layout? each background size is 100%

Comment: vucko those are fixed div sizes for sections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is set up events when the window reaches certain scroll points.  You can do this via $.scroll() or use a library such as [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/). As an example when using waypoints:

```
$('#target').waypoint(function(dir)) {
  $('nav <a> elements').removeClass('selected');
  switch(dir) {
    case 'down':
      $('corresponding <a> selector').addClass('selected');
      break;
    case 'up':
      $('previous <a> selector').addClass('selected');
  }
}
```

This would need to be done for each target element.