# Jquery addClass Tag doenst work

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have a navigation called #nav ul li a. In this list, I want to add the class active to the element on which has been clicked.

This is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
$('#nav ul li a').click(function() {
           $('#nav ul li a').removeClass('active"');

           $(this).addClass('active');
           return false;
        });
});
```

and this is my html

```
<header id="header"> 
    <h1 id="logo"><a href="#intro">DerW&auml;schestuhl</a></h1>
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#one" class="active" id="uebersicht-btn">&Uuml;bersicht</a></li>
            <li><a href="#two" class="" id="aussehen-btn">Aussehen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#work" class="" id="funktionen-btn">Funktionen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#produktion" class=""id="produktionen-btn">Produktion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" class="" id="kaufen-btn">Kaufen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

and here is my jsfiddle to show the stylesheets: http://jsfiddle.net/Usgk3/

Do you guys have any idea why it isnt working? I cant find the mistake

Comment: removeClass('active"') <- is wrong - there is one `"` to much :)

Comment: removed it, but it's still not working! sorry

Comment: It's working for me. If you were checking that in the jsFiddle that you provide, don't forget to include the jquery library you are using, without it the `$` object would not work.

Comment: its working but - your js fiddle is without jQuery

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle is no jQuery linked and:

```
$('#nav ul li a').removeClass('active"');
```

Remove **"** from **('active"')**.

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Usgk3/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
 $('#nav ul li a').click(function(e) {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');

       $(this).addClass('active');
       return false;
    });
  });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Usgk3/4/)

Comment: @fjw then how do you want that functionality?. this is the right one.

Comment: Okay, it is working. Forgot to check jquery. Do you know how I can add the class to the menu element without clicking it, but by scrolling? its a parallax page

Comment: @fjw or you can bind the scroll event - like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979827/change-active-menu-item-on-page-scroll

Comment: @Mr. iC, thats weird. It works in jsfiddle, but neither in dreamweaver, nor in safari/firefox. why? http://jsfiddle.net/LwZV2/

Comment: @fjw its not even working in jsfiddle - you have to remove the `return` false from ^ this example since this will prevent the link from jumping. Then its working fine for me. If its still not working just ask another Question...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `"` in string `'active"'`:

```
$('#nav ul li a').removeClass('active"');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Usgk3/10/). With settings:
[image: fiddler settins]

Comment: Added fiddle link. See also Fiddle settings (jQuery added and onLoad removed)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing jQuery in your fiddle demo.

You also need yo use:

```
$('#nav ul li a').removeClass('active');
```

instead of:

```
$('#nav ul li a').removeClass('active"');
// --                                ^ Remove this
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Usgk3/11/)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

**$('#nav ul li a').removeClass('active"');**

Remove the **"** in the enclosed ('active"');

This should be like

**$('#nav ul li a').removeClass('active');**

That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you don't put jquery in your fiddle i assume you use a new jquery version, so better use `.on( 'click' )`, not `.click()`
2. Keep it simple, replace `$('#nav ul li a')` with `$('#nav a')`. According to your markup it is exactly same stuff
3. Check more about `.siblings()` in jquery.

Your working code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Usgk3/18/)

Comment: thank you! It works. Do you know how I can scroll and when I've reached '#work' for example, then add the class to the menu. So not by clicking, but by scrolling.