# If scroll to section, return section title

Tags: javascript

I have a single page with multiple sections. I also have a fixed header bar. When I scroll to each section, I want the section title to display inside the fixed header bar.

I tried this:

```
$('a.icons').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('section.icons').offset().top - 100}, 300);

    $icon = $('.style-menu-icon');

    $icon.text(function () {
        //change text based on condition
        return "Icons";
    });

  });
```

This is saying or at least is trying to say: 
Click on link icons. 
Scroll to section.icons div, offset -100px 
return the string "Icons" inside the .style-menu-icon div class

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: How do I display the sections title inside of a div when scrolled to that particular section?

Comment: You can use bootstrap nav for it. Refer: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/

Comment: Does this mean the `text` method fails to do that? Listening to `scroll` event is recommended as when the user scrolls the page manually the text is not updated.

Comment: @SaiDeepak Bootstrap is _expensive_ for this.

Comment: The script I posted actually works, but it just displays the title on click, how can I display the title on scroll, and for multiple sections? Will I have make an individual script for each section or can I grab the .text from the section title div within each section?

Comment: You can listen to `scroll` event of the `window` object and filter the matching  section. In fact your  `click` handler shouldn't change the text. One `scroll` handler is sufficient. You are also hard-coding the click handlers which is not recommended, think more dynamic and DRY!

Comment: Its free of cost just check it

Comment: @SaiDeepak Expensive performance-wise, I know it's free! :) A sane developer doesn't load a framework for using just one of it's features!

Comment: in order to "filter the matching section" do I need to use a for loop?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Please check this somehow related question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979827/change-active-menu-item-on-page-scroll