# Highlight an active menu item (anchor) on click and/or scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, anchor, highlight

Nothing I've found here and on the web works on the website http://lexic-on.ru/ru/ (Joomla based)
I tried to use this solution [Change Active Menu Item on Page Scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979827/change-active-menu-item-on-page-scroll)
but it didn't work

UPD:
I put the exact JS code 
`<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){ 
// Cache selectors var lastId, topMenu = $("#sp-main-menu")` ----> my menu id

.......

```
.end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
   }                  
});
});//]]> 
</script>
```

as well as jquery 2.3.1 link from Google in the `head`

Menu looks like this:

```
<div id="sp-main-menu" class="visible-desktop">
                <ul class="sp-menu level-0"><li class="menu-item active first">
```

....`<a href="#services" class="menu-item" ><span class="menu"><span class="menu-title">Услуги</span></span></a></li>`.....

It works perfectly on a test page without other scripts. But nothing works on the site. I guess some other script conflicts with this one.

Comment: If the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979827/change-active-menu-item-on-page-scroll didn't work then you didn't implement it correctly. Post your code and maybe we can help you fix it.

Comment: I think I've found an error in the script: if a menu has at least one non-anchor link then the script  doesn't work.
By default Joomla has HOME as first and obligatory main menu item which cannot be anchor link. So everything is messed up. What can I do?

Comment: The script from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979827/change-active-menu-item-on-page-scroll should still work on all <a> tags it just won't work on the HOME link if it's not an anchor. You may have to code something special for the home link since it's not an anchor therefore doesn't have an href, but I can't help with that without seeing the actual html sent to the browser.