# jQuery anchor link highlight when target div in view not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scroll

I'm following the top answer to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979827/change-active-menu-item-on-page-scroll).

Direct link to the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/).

I tried implemented the same strategy except one part doesn't work, specifically the last line. My structure is a little different so I had to change it.

Original:

```
 menuItems
  .parent().removeClass("active")
  .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").parent().addClass("active");
```

I had to get rid of parent() because my setup is a little different, but that breaks it.

```
 menuItems
  .removeClass("active")
  .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").addClass("active");
```

It half works if I keep the first `.parent()`, it just doesn't remove the class like I'd like it too. So my question is, what is wrong with the syntax of my version, that does not include `.parent()`?

Here is my HTML structure:

```
<div class="content-wrap>
  <a class="side-link>Menu item 1</a>
  <a class="side-link>Menu item 2</a>
  <a class="side-link>Menu item 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery when you are searching for element to highlight you need to step one step up in DOM so you can find sibling elements:

```
   menuItems
     .removeClass("active").parent()
     .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").addClass("active");
```

Working example:

```js
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;
   
   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
   
   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .removeClass("active").parent()
         .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").addClass("active");
   }                   
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 6000px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}

#top-menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}


#top-menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 25px 7px 25px;
    width: 6em;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: .5s all ease-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s all ease-out;
    transition: .5s all ease-out;
    border-top: 3px solid white;
    color: #aaa;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
}

#top-menu a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

#top-menu a.active {
    border-top: 3px solid #333;
    color: #333;
}

#foo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}

#bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 800px;
}

#baz {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-wrap" id="top-menu">
  <a class="side-link active" href="#">Menu item 1</a>
  <a class="side-link" href="#bar">Menu item 2</a>
  <a class="side-link" href="#baz">Menu item 3</a>
</div>


<a id="foo">Foo</a>


<a id="bar">Bar</a>


<a id="baz">Baz</a>
```